# How to match those minions which don't have a certain custom grain?

Tags: salt-stack

Some of the minions have a grain like `foo: bar` while others don't have that grain. What should I do to match those minions which don't have the `foo` grain?

I have tried `salt -G 'foo:'` and `salt -P 'foo:^$'` but neither of them work.

Assume that there are 3 minions:

```
minion1:
    ----------
    foo: 
        bar
minion2:
    ----------
    foo: 
        baz
minion3:
    ----------
    foo:
```

Both minion1 and minion2 have the grain `foo` and minion3 is not defined this grain. How to match minion3 ONLY?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-P` (`Grains PCRE`):

```
salt -P 'foo:^(?!bar)'
```

Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for `re` module says:

> (?!...)
>
> Matches if ... doesn’t match next. This is a negative lookahead
>   assertion. For example, Isaac (?!Asimov) will match 'Isaac ' only if
>   it’s not followed by 'Asimov'.

or just simply use a [compound](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/targeting/compound.html) match with negation:

```
salt -C 'not G@foo:bar'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answering. I have detailed the question with an example. In that example, your commands will only match "minions whose `foo` is not 'bar'".

Comment: Can you show the output from `salt minion3 grains.item foo`?

Comment: The grain `foo` of minion3 is never defined. So output will show the key `foo` only and show the value as nothing, like the example I gave above.

Comment: You can display the output in JSON format to see the value: `salt --out json minion3 grains.item foo`. If it was never set then it should be an empty string. This should catch both cases, an empty string or `None` (`null`) value: `salt -C 'P@foo: or P@foo:^$'`. If it doesn't then try `grains.ls` to see if this grain actually exist at all for this box.